# Removing Extra Line Endings with Python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

When converting HTML from sites to plain text we get a lot of extra line breaks. We want a maximum of 1 adjacent line break. This is the function we are using, but it seems ugly, and doesn't hit all use cases. Is there a more Pythonic way to achieve this results with less ugly code?

```
    def clean_up_lines(message_text):
        text_str = str(message_text)
        text_data = text_str.replace(chr(13), "[EOL]")
        text_data = text_data.replace(chr(10), "[EOL]")
        text_data = text_data.replace("\n", "[EOL]")
        text_data = text_data.replace("\r", "[EOL]")
        for x in range(0, 10):
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]       [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]      [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]     [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]    [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]   [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]  [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL] [EOL]", "[EOL]")
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL][EOL]", "[EOL]")
        for x in range(0, 8):
            text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL][EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text_data = text_data.replace("[EOL]", "\n")
        return text_data
```

Comment: What is your input and its expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a regex replace to replace several adjacent instances of newlines by a single one:

```
document.replace(r"\n+",r"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `re.sub()` to substitute every chain of `\n` by `\n\n` if you want one extra line-break. Use `\n` if you just want one line-break.

```
import re

s = 'Line1\n\n\nLine4'

print(re.sub(r'\n+', '\n\n', s))
#print(re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', s))
```

Output:

```
Line1

Line4
```